# Ajax.ActionLink Navigates to new Page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-javascript

Using ASP .NET MVC 4.5, jQuery 1.8.3 and Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax v 2.0.30116.0.

I have the following code in a partial view:

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "DeletePost", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "post" + post.Id, InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "POST" })
```

I see the following the page source:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

I have the following in the web.config

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Clicking the "Delete" link navigates to the action url specified for the ActionLink:

```
http://localhost/Communities/DeletePost#
```

instead of leaving me on the page and making the AJAX request.

What's going on here?

Comment: What exactly is the method you're calling doing?  Returning an `EmptyResult` a `PartialView` or what?  That would be the first place I look.

Comment: it returns Content(string.Empty)

Comment: Also, why would that matter?

Comment: In reference to what @JoshBurgess said, I'd wonder if View was not found and you triggered a 404 based redirect. Which obviously is NOT the case here. All the more I'd like to see what Firebug or Chrome JS Debugger would say

Comment: Otherwise your code looks frustratingly right. you have your JQ files and your appsettings. The only icky i can spot was the relative path and that you tried fixing. It's that knock-head-in-wall feeling

Comment: I've run into situations where an overridden method returns the unexpected type. If you've got two `delete` methods on the same controller, one designed to serve a full view, one to serve an AJAX response, I'd be concerned with the routing parsing the request incorrectly. Like @DaveA said, I'd want to see exactly what was coming back across the wire.

Comment: I do see that the url is correct for the action I want...and clicking the link (even though it navigates to a new page) does in fact call the desired action.

Comment: I attached Chrome's debugger and upon clicking the "Delete" link, I get the error "SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12". I see the newSelector local variable is ":input[data-val=true]"...which makes me think it has something to do with unobtrusive ajax...but I could be wrong...